# Safari iframe's service worker loops infinitely and iframe is a white screen (not in other browsers, not in a new tab)

Tags: vue.js, safari, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have 2 webapplications build in vue. One application is some sort of wrapper for all the applications a company has and it loads several projects via an iframe (And one of them is the other web-application build in vue).

Both projects have the vue-pwa plugin installed.
When opening the wrapper project in the safari browser on a mac and browsing to the iframe with the other vue application the screen is blank and i'm seeing that there are an unlimited count of console.logs: `Service worker has been registered.` from the register hook in the registerServiceWorker.js

The moment i open the contents of that iframe in a seccond tab of safari, these console.logs stop and the page is normally loaded and functioning.

Does anyone have an idea for a solution, or how to debug what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that i needed to set the header `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/`
Weird thing is that the code was executed, it was just not visible. And other browsers don't seem to bother that since there was no `X-Frame-Options` that blocked it.